# ffmpeg to convert *.mkv to mp4 using h.265

Tags: h.265

i was wondering, i have various misc video files in mp4 and mkv with various codecs and i wanted to convert all to mp4 with h.265 with aac as the codecs

so i was wondering can FFMpeg handle that?

I can then use a shell script and convert a bunch of videos once i get the command line working as desired

subtitles can be embedded but off by default etc?

if FFMpeg cannot so this can another tool?

Answer (score -1):

At seems that ffmpeg has now been updated to support H.265 so my question is now moot.